# JGit: Fastest way to retrieve the File Object Blob without accessing its data

Tags: java, git, jgit

I need the last commit with affected the path something similar to `git log -1 -- path`.

Currently, I am doing this

```
TreeWalk.forPath(repo, filepath, rootCommit.getTree()).getObjectId(0)
```

Is there any faster way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the Porcelain command for "log", it uses a RevWalk internally, so it might run with different timings, however I am not sure which one will be faster, it may also depend on the repository size and structure to some degree...

```
    Iterable<RevCommit> logs = new Git(repository).log()
            .addPath("README.md")
            .setMaxCount(1)
            .call();
    for(RevCommit rev : logs) {
        System.out.println("Commit: " + rev);
    }
```